# How would I go about making rods that join two faces in an object with random scale and rotation?

Tags: modeling

So, as the question says, I would like to join the two selected faces of the object with rods.[image]

To better illustrate what I mean, I did  this manually by randomly rotating the bars and using a boolean intersect modifier (I would want way more bars and varying thicknesses).
[image]

My first thought was to use a particle system, but I couldn't get it to behave in the way I wanted to. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Your boolean method is fine for what you're showing.  Can you specify what it is you dislike about that method?

Comment: I want a large number of rods (say 40), and I would want to do this for around 4 objects. I don't think its practical to do that manually.

Comment: Does it matter if the rods intersect?

Comment: It's as practical as any other method-- if you duplicate a rod, it'll come into the world with the same Boolean modifier as the original.  Meanwhile, position, rotation, and scale (thickness) are things you need to specify with any method of doing this (although one easy way to specify it for a large selection of objects is with a randomize transform.)  Select your 4 bars and duplicate 10 times, that's not so hard.  (Yes, a particle system could also create your rods, for use with a boolean after conversion.)

Comment: I'd rather the bars don't intersect but its not a necessity.